# Determine set of solution of linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If we have linear operator $L:R[x]→R^2$ defined with $L:u→((u(2)),(u′(2)))$ determine set of solutions of equation $L(u)=(3,−2)$.I know that is for first and other bigger degree solution only vector $7-2x$.How to write set of solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The operator $L$ is linear. It implies that if $u_0$ is the solution $7-2x$, and if you write $u = u_0 + v$, then the equation becomes
$$L(v) = (0,0)$$
so that $v(2) = 0$ and $v^\prime(2) = 0$. Can you find $v$ ?

Comment: Vector v is vector in nullspace?Then set of solution is 7-2x plus nullspace?

Comment: Yes, the set of solution is $7-2x$ plus nullspace, but you can say much more about polynomials in the nullspace.

Answer (score 0):

If $u(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, then$$u(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n.$$Therefore$$u(2)=3\iff a_0+2a_1+\cdots+2^na_n=3$$and$$u'(2)=-2\iff a_1+2a_2+\cdots+n2^{n-1}a_n=-2.$$So, the solutions of your system are those $u(x)$ such that $a_0+2a_1=3-2^2a_2-\cdots-2^na_n$ and that $a_1=-2-2a_2-\cdots-n2^{n-1}a_n$.